# How to express the column PATH relative to the TABLE-PATH SAS XML MAPS

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, sas

I want to read an XML file into some SAS datasets. A SAS XML map uses X-Path (version 1) to refer to elements in the XML that should generate a row and other X-Paht expressions that to refer to elements or attributes that containt the column values. Unfortunately the values I retreive are not always linked to the rows I need.

## Simple example: looking aside

From this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<street>
    <house>
        <houseNumber>1</houseNumber>
        <resident>Albert</resident>
        <pet>dog</pet>
    </house>
    <house>
        <houseNumber>2</houseNumber>
        <resident>Bea</resident>
        <resident>Clemance</resident>
    </house>
    <house>
        <houseNumber>3</houseNumber>
        <!--remark: for sale-->
    </house>
    <house>
        <houseNumber>4</houseNumber>
        <resident>Dave</resident>
        <resident>Eve</resident>
        <pet>Cat</pet>
    </house>
</street>
```

I would like to extract  this data

```
Obs    houseNumber    name      pet
1              1    Albert      dog
2              2    Bea              
3              2    Clemance    
4              4    Dave        cat
5              4    Eve         cat
```

But using this map

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<SXLEMAP name="AUTO_GEN" version="2.1">
    <NAMESPACES count="0"/>
    <TABLE description="residents" name="resident">
        <TABLE-PATH syntax="XPath">resident</TABLE-PATH>
        <COLUMN name="houseNumber" retain="YES"> 
            <PATH syntax="XPath">houseNumber</PATH>
            <TYPE>numeric</TYPE>
            <DATATYPE>integer</DATATYPE>
        </COLUMN>
        <COLUMN name="name">
            <PATH syntax="XPath">resident</PATH>
            <TYPE>character</TYPE>
            <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
            <LENGTH>32</LENGTH>
        </COLUMN>
        <COLUMN name="pet">
            <PATH syntax="XPath">pet</PATH>
            <TYPE>character</TYPE>
            <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
            <LENGTH>32</LENGTH>
        </COLUMN>
    </TABLE>
</SXLEMAP>
```

And this code

```
filename  SXLELIB 'C:\MyFolder\xml.xml';
filename  SXLEMAP 'C:\MyFolder\map.map';
libname   SXLELIB xmlv2 xmlmap=SXLEMAP access=READONLY;

proc print data=SXLELIB.resident(obs=100); 
run;
```

I get this:

```
Obs    houseNumber  name        pet
1              1    Albert      
2              2    Bea         bird
3              2    Clemance    
4              4    Dave        
5              4    Eve
```

_This is a verry simple example, Joe elegantly solve on 12 july 2017.
However, his solution does not work for my real life problem, hence I supply a

## More complicated example : heterogeneour names

### From this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<street>
    <house>
        <houseNumber>1</houseNumber>
        <adult>
            <name>Albert</name>
            <age>41</age>
        </adult>
        <child>
            <name>Ken</name>
            <age>1</age>
        </child>
    </house>
    <house>
        <houseNumber>2</houseNumber>
        <adult>
            <name>Bea</name>
            <age>42</age>
        </adult>
        <adult>
            <name>Clemance</name>
            <age>43</age>
        </adult>
    </house>
    <appartment>
        <houseNumber>3</houseNumber>
        <suiteNumber>1</suiteNumber>
        <!--remark: for rent-->
    </appartment>
    <appartment>
        <houseNumber>3</houseNumber>
        <suiteNumber>2</suiteNumber>
        <adult>
            <name>Ivette</name>
            <age>45</age>
        <adult>
        <adult>
            <name>Jacque</name>
            <age>51</age>
        <adult>
        <child>
            <name>Lea</name>
            <age>2</age>
        </child>
        <child>
            <name>Marie</name>
            <age>3</age>
        </child>
    </appartment>
    <appartment>
        <houseNumber>3</houseNumber>
        <suiteNumber>2</suiteNumber>
        <adult>
            <name>Henri</name>
            <age>44</age>
        <adult>
    </appartment>
    <house>
        <houseNumber>4</houseNumber>
        <adult>
            <name>Dave</name>
            <age>46</age>
        </adult>
        <adult>
            <name>Eve</name>
            <age>51</age>
        </adult>
    </house>
    <house>
        <houseNumber>5</houseNumber>
        <adult>
            <name>Francis</name>
            <age>47</age>
        </adult>
        <adult>
            <name>Gertrude</name>
            <age>48</age>
        </adult>
    </house>
    <house>
        <houseNumber>6</houseNumber>
        <!--remark: for sale-->
    </house>
</street>
```

### I would like to extract

```
 Obs  name        age number suite
 1    Albert      41    1    .
 2    Ken         1     1    .
 3    Bea         42    2    .
 4    Clemance    43    2    .
 5    Ivette      45    3    2
 6    Jacque      45    3    2
 7    Lea         2     3    2
 8    Marie       3     3    2
 9    Henri       44    3    3
10    Dave        46    4    .
11    Eve         51    4    .
12    Francis     47    5    .
13    Gertrude    48    5    .
```

#### Using relative address from name, something like this

```
<TABLE description="relative address from name" name="resident_1">
    <TABLE-PATH syntax="XPath">name</TABLE-PATH>
    <COLUMN name="name">
        <PATH syntax="XPath">.</PATH>
        <TYPE>character</TYPE>
        <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
        <LENGTH>32</LENGTH>
    </COLUMN>
    <COLUMN name="age" retain="YES"> 
        <PATH syntax="XPath">../age</PATH>
        <TYPE>numeric</TYPE>
        <DATATYPE>integer</DATATYPE>
    </COLUMN>
    <COLUMN name="number">
        <PATH syntax="XPath">../../number</PATH>
        <TYPE>numeric</TYPE>
        <DATATYPE>integer</DATATYPE>
    </COLUMN>
    <COLUMN name="suite">
        <PATH syntax="XPath">../../suiteNumber</PATH>
        <TYPE>numeric</TYPE>
        <DATATYPE>integer</DATATYPE>
    </COLUMN>
</TABLE>
```

#### but that only gives me missing values

### So, I tried absolute addresses

```
<TABLE description="name based absolute addresses" name="resident_2">
    <TABLE-PATH syntax="XPath">name</TABLE-PATH>
    <COLUMN name="name">
        <PATH syntax="XPath">name</PATH>
        <TYPE>character</TYPE>
        <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
        <LENGTH>32</LENGTH>
    </COLUMN>
    <COLUMN name="age" retain="YES"> 
        <PATH syntax="XPath">age</PATH>
        <TYPE>numeric</TYPE>
        <DATATYPE>integer</DATATYPE>
    </COLUMN>
    <COLUMN name="number">
        <PATH syntax="XPath">houseNumber</PATH>
        <TYPE>numeric</TYPE>
        <DATATYPE>integer</DATATYPE>
    </COLUMN>
    <COLUMN name="suite">
        <PATH syntax="XPath">suiteNumber</PATH>
        <TYPE>numeric</TYPE>
        <DATATYPE>integer</DATATYPE>
    </COLUMN>
</TABLE>
```

#### Which is better, but lea     ves me with two problems

- As values are forgotten once used, I still have somme missing values
- As ages come after names, ages are read too late, hence shifted downward

:

```
 Obs  name        age number suite
 1    Albert      .     1    .
 2    Ken         41    .    .
 3    Bea         1     2    .
 4    Clemance    42    .    .
 5    Ivette      43    3    2
 6    Jacque      45    .    .
 7    Lea         45    .    .
 8    Marie       2     .    .
 9    Henri       3     3    3
 10   Dave        44    4    .
 11   Eve         46    .    .
 12   Francis     51    5    .
 13   Gertrude    47    .    .
```

### So I tried starting from `age` instead of `name` and using the retain option

```
<TABLE description="age based absolute addresses" name="resident_3">
    <TABLE-PATH syntax="XPath">age</TABLE-PATH>
    <COLUMN name="name">
        <PATH syntax="XPath">name</PATH>
        <TYPE>character</TYPE>
        <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
        <LENGTH>32</LENGTH>
    </COLUMN>
    <COLUMN name="age" retain="YES"> 
        <PATH syntax="XPath">age</PATH>
        <TYPE>numeric</TYPE>
        <DATATYPE>integer</DATATYPE>
    </COLUMN>
    <COLUMN name="number" retain="yes">
        <PATH syntax="XPath">houseNumber</PATH>
        <TYPE>numeric</TYPE>
        <DATATYPE>integer</DATATYPE>
    </COLUMN>
    <COLUMN name="suite" retain="yes">
        <PATH syntax="XPath">suiteNumber</PATH>
        <TYPE>numeric</TYPE>
        <DATATYPE>integer</DATATYPE>
    </COLUMN>
</TABLE>
```

#### Which is also lea     ves me with two problems

- As houuse and suite numbers are now retained for eve     r, I drag them along too long
- I loose people with missing ages *(i.e. Jacques)*

:

```
Obs  name      age number suite
1    Albert    41    1    .
2    Ken       1     1    .
3    Bea       42    2    .
4    Clemance  43    2    .
5    Ivette    45    3    2
6    Lea       2     3    2
7    Marie     3     3    2
8    Henri     44    3    3
9    Dave      46    4    3
10    Eve      51    4    3
11    Francis  47    5    3
12    Gertrude 48    5    3
```

Does anyone have a better solution?

## The real problem : Reading Addresses from CRS or FATCA files

I posed my question after attempting in vain to read back address data from files I create to read back address data I wrote to xml files to report foreign account holders using the [Common Reporting Standard User Guide](http://file:///C:/Users/A01549/Downloads/CRS_User_Guide_2_0.pdf)

Addresses have only one mandatory field, the `ResCountryCode`, which occurs first. They occur in moth `Individual`s and `Organization`s.

Answer (score 1):

I think it *may* be possible to do this in XPath as a single table, but in my experience SAS's support of the parent-child-sibling elements of XPath (that you'd have to use to specify this properly) is ... poor.

Much much easier is to import as two tables and merge.  SAS supports that very cleanly.

Using two tables, one the automap of "resident" the other the automap of "pet", you can do this easily.

```
filename  SXLELIB 'C:\temp\test.xml';
filename  SXLEMAP 'C:\temp\test.map';
libname   SXLELIB xmlv2 xmlmap=SXLEMAP access=READONLY;

proc print data=SXLELIB.resident(obs=100); 
run;
proc print data=SXLELIB.pet(obs=100); 
run;
```

Merge on `house_ordinal` and you're done.

Here's the details:

```
<TABLE description="house" name="pet">
    <TABLE-PATH syntax="XPath">/street/house/pet</TABLE-PATH>

    <COLUMN class="ORDINAL" name="house_ORDINAL">
        <INCREMENT-PATH beginend="BEGIN" syntax="XPath">/street/house</INCREMENT-PATH>
        <TYPE>numeric</TYPE>
        <DATATYPE>integer</DATATYPE>
    </COLUMN>

    <COLUMN name="houseNumber">
        <PATH syntax="XPath">/street/house/houseNumber</PATH>
        <TYPE>numeric</TYPE>
        <DATATYPE>integer</DATATYPE>
    </COLUMN>

    <COLUMN name="pet">
        <PATH syntax="XPath">/street/house/pet</PATH>
        <TYPE>character</TYPE>
        <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
        <LENGTH>3</LENGTH>
    </COLUMN>

</TABLE>

<TABLE description="resident" name="resident">
    <TABLE-PATH syntax="XPath">/street/house/resident</TABLE-PATH>

    <COLUMN class="ORDINAL" name="house_ORDINAL">
        <INCREMENT-PATH beginend="BEGIN" syntax="XPath">/street/house</INCREMENT-PATH>
        <TYPE>numeric</TYPE>
        <DATATYPE>integer</DATATYPE>
    </COLUMN>

    <COLUMN class="ORDINAL" name="resident_ORDINAL">
        <INCREMENT-PATH beginend="BEGIN" syntax="XPath">/street/house/resident</INCREMENT-PATH>
        <TYPE>numeric</TYPE>
        <DATATYPE>integer</DATATYPE>
    </COLUMN>

    <COLUMN name="resident">
        <PATH syntax="XPath">/street/house/resident</PATH>
        <TYPE>character</TYPE>
        <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
        <LENGTH>8</LENGTH>
    </COLUMN>

</TABLE>
```

Comment: Thanks Joe. This solves the simplifyed problem I posed above, but not the more complicated problem I realy have. I will edit the question later to show why.